# Hashmap's getValue returns Object

Tags: java, hashmap

I've got the following data structure:

```
CFU66=[{Bild1=CFU6606}, {Bild2=CFU6603}, {Bild3=CFU6605}, {Bild4=CFU6601}, {Bild5=CFU6602}]
```

Structure: `Hashmap_1(String Key, List(Hashmap_2(String Key, String Value)))`

I'm trying to access the values from `Hashmap_2`:

```
// for each Hashmap_1 entry
for (Map.Entry<String, List> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
   // for each List in entry.getValue
   for (List<HashMap> hashList : csvDictEntry.getValue()) {
      // for each Hashmap_2 in List
      for (HashMap<String, String> hashListDict : hashList) {
         // for each entry in Hashmap_2 print Value
         for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :hashListDict.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The compiler gives the message, that `csvDictEntry.getValue()` in the second for-loop returns a `Object` instead of a `Hashmap`. Why?

However, I'm pretty new to Java and I'm sure there is a more convenient way to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? print all values in `hashmap_2`?

Comment: Actually I want to give the values from `hashmap_2` to a JavaBean with setters and getters.

Comment: Because type of `csvDictEntry` is `Map.Entry<String, List>`, not `Map.Entry<String, List<HashMap>>`. You ware probably warned about raw-type of `List` by compiler.

Comment: Side note: consider to replace `HashMap` with `Map`.

Comment: @Puce: Why is it better to replace `HashMap` with `Map`?

Comment: @jwi I recommend you the book "Effective Java", by Joshua Bloch, and regarding your question especially "Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
```

I assume that type of `csvDict` is

```
Map<String, List> csvDict = ...;
```

where based on your data example `CFU66=[{Bild1=CFU6606}, {Bild2=CFU6603}, {Bild3=CFU6605}, {Bild4=CFU6601}, {Bild5=CFU6602}]`

it should be

```
Map<String, List<Map<String,String>>> csvDict = ...;
```

Problem with your reference type is that `List` is raw-type, which means that its actual type is unknown (it can store any kind of Objects) so `Object` is type which compiler assumes when you are trying to iterate over such list so when normally we would expect

```
for (Type t : List<Type>)
```

for raw type we are getting

```
for (Object o : rawList)
```

---

Other problem is way you are iterating because even if we change your reference to proper type

```
for (List<HashMap> hashList : csvDictEntry.getValue())
```

will not compile because `getValue()` returns `List<HashMap>` so your loop would iterate over `HashMap`s, not `List` of `HashMap`s so it should be

```
for (HashMap hashList : csvDictEntry.getValue())
```

Hint: try to avoid concrete types in generics, use parent type if it is possible, like interface or abstract type. This will allow you later easily changing actual type, for instance from `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap`.

So your iteration should look like

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, String>>> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
    // for each Map in List stored as value
    for (Map<String, String> hashListDict : csvDictEntry.getValue()) {
        // for each entry in hmap_2 print Value
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashListDict.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/NzxdCc)

---

BTW in Java 8 your code could be simplified to

```
    csvDict.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.getValue().stream())
    .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Your solution looks good to me, but the compiler says: `Error:(29, 90) java: incompatible types
  required:java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>>
found:java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.util.List>`

Comment: @jwi What is the code in line which throws that error?

Comment: Got it! I've missed to put `csvDict<String, List<Map<String, String>>>` also in the method declaration as argument. Anyway, your answer was very helpful. Thanks & Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

this

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
```

should be

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, String>>> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
```

Comment: It's better to also specify the type parameters for HashMap, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Just write all your types

```
    Map<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> csvDict = null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
        // for each List in entry.getValue
        for (HashMap<String, String> hashList : csvDictEntry.getValue()) {
            // for each Hashmap_2 in List
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashList.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

And also you have extra `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by others you forgot to use <> after 'List' on your first line of code. Therefore, the compiler doesn't know what kind of elements are in those lists. 
Also you're making it unnecessarily complex by iterating over `entrySet` when you're only interested in the values.

Map has 3 functions to iterate:

1. [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) - if you're only interested in the keys
2. [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) - if you're only interested in the values
3. [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) - if you're interested in both

So in your case...

```
for (Map<String,String> map : csvDict.values()) {
    for (String value : map.values()) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the first for,what you are currently doing is retrieving a generic list,instead of a particular list.

The declaration of entry set is:

```
 Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>   <-------     entrySet()
 Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map.
```

so you should reconsider chaging your first for to:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<HashMap>> csvDictEntry : csvDict.entrySet()) {
```